# railsでcarrierwave+rmagickについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails

carrierwaveでDBに保存し、Viewで様々なサイトに書いてあるように:thumbを引数に取ってリサイズされた画像を表示したいのですがうまくいきません。

例:@image.image.url(:thumb) と様々なサイトに書いていますが、このように書くとurlというメソッドはない、引数の数が(1for0)となりうまくいきません。

どうかおしえてください。

Comment: 具体的なエラーの内容が分からないのでエラーの内容をコピペして貼るとよさそうです

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/9357

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process resize_to_fit: [800, 800]

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [200,200]
  end

end
```

とアップローダーに定義したあとであれば `@image.image.thumb.url` でアクセス出来ます。何かエラー出てる場合はエラーを教えていただければ。

おそらくアップローダーにversion定義されていないのではないかと想定しています。
困ったら[carrierwave公式ドキュメント（英語）](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#adding-versions)の方法に合わせるとよくいくことが多いです。

Answer (score 0):

@image.image_url(:thumb)または@image.image.thumb.urlでできるかと思います。